# Is making a method synchronized when the method is only called in a synchronized block redundant? What happens on the OS level?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Let's say you have a method foo() **that is only called in a synchronized block.**

Is making the method

`synchronized void foo() {..}`

versus just

`void foo() {..}`

redundant or bad practice, or does it make the method's intent clearer? Does having the synchronized keyword on the method signature make the program slower? I'm wondering what the better practice is, or if I'm missing part of the big picture.

Thanks.

Comment: How can you be assured the method will only be called in the synchronized block? If the method needs to be synchronized, make it synchronized. Don't make assumptions on how the method will be used over the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Just in my design, I have it that way. So it seems like it's best to be explicit and just make it synchronized... okay.

Comment: Can you make foo() private?

Comment: You do not specify, so does the synchronized block use same lock object than the syncronized method (which uses *this*, of course)? If not, your whole question becomes kind of asking the wrong question...

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this means the `foo()` is not an atomic action itself, it probably does not preserve invariants, it is only part of the grander synchronization scheme.

Then it should *not* declare `synchronized`, otherwise reader might get the wrong idea; and it is a bit slower too.

Instead, you could

```
void foo()
{
    assert Thread.holdsLock(this);
    ...
}
```

it serves 2 purposes

1. document that this method can only be invoked within an outer `synchonized(this)` block
2. check that requirement at runtime (I'll enable assersion for all non-production runs)

Answer (score 1):

It's not redundant and in practice it's reasonably common to synchronise on locks you already hold.

APIs that have clearly defined boundaries between what's threadsafe and what's not are easier to work with, and the best boundary is probably at the class level. So, if the rest of the class is threadsafe and the foo() method will be threadsafe if synchronised then you may as well do it and make a note of it in your class doc. If synchronising foo() will give you an API with mixed threadsafe and non-threadsafe calls then that's going to lead to confusion later on.

Regarding performance I doubt it'll be an issue (uncontested locks should have minimal overhead). Get the code working and then see if you need to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your `foo()` method is in a class A, and the caller code (which calls it inside a synchronized block) is in another class B.

My advice is not to make methods of A `synchronized`, because in single-threaded programs invocations will be systematically slower.

It is better to make the client classes (such as B) to carry out the synchronization job, by using synchronized blocks, as you pointed out.

In summary, my advice is to not declare the method synchronized, because it is more flexible: you can make thread-safe programs using your class with external synchronized blocks and also make fast single-threaded applications. You can also warn your users that your class A is not thread-safe.